# JQuery Swap Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I need to swap the column in a table but retain the current edit value of the column.

Here is my code:

```
$(this).click(function () {
    var $td = $(this).closest('td.container');
    var $tds = [];
    $td.closest('tr').children('td').each(function () { $tds.push($(this)); });
    for (var i = $td.index() + 1; i < $tds.length; i++)
        $tds[i - 1].html($tds[i].html()).addClass('border');
    $tds[$tds.length - 1].html('').removeClass('border');
});
```

However, if I have textboxes and editing the textboxes when swapping the column, the textbox values will disappear.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqmj64gb/43/).

```
Step to reproduce:
1. Enter some text in textbox in column #3
2. Click on "Delete Button" in column #2
3. You will see the text entered in step #1 will disappear.
```

Any idea how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're appending the HTML of the `table` to the previous cell. The HTML does not contain the amended `value` property of the `input` elements the user typed in to. To fix this copy the elements from the DOM, not their HTML.

Also note that your logic can be simplified. Firstly, you don't need the `each()` loop as you can apply the `click()` event handler to the collection of `button` elements directly. You can also work with the jQuery object itself instead of looping through it to create a pointless array of jQuery objects which you need to again loop through.

```js
$('#tblContent button').click(function() {
  var $container = $(this).closest('td.container');
  var $content = $container.next().children()
  $container.empty().append($content);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 256px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.container.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblContent">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='container border'>
        <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%'">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" data-name="isactive" value="1">Column 1 OK?</label>
              </td>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Put something here 1" maxlength="64" style="width:100%" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Put something here 2" maxlength="64" style="width:100%" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><button disabled>Deleteme</button></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class='container border'>
        <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%'">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" data-name="isactive" value="1">Column 2 OK</label>
              </td>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Put something here 3" maxlength="64" style="width:100%" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Put something here 4" maxlength="64" style="width:100%" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><button>Deleteme</button></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class='container border'>
        <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%'">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" data-name="isactive" value="1">Column 3 OK</label>
              </td>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Put something here 5" maxlength="64" style="width:100%" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Put something here 6" maxlength="64" style="width:100%" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><button disabled>Deleteme</button></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Finally, I'd suggest you review how you're structuring the HTML of this page. It's dangerously close to the bad practice of the late 90s of using `table` elements for layout. `table` should only be used for tabular data.

The layout you are trying to achieve can be made far more simply using `div` along with some CSS to style it, in a fraction of the amount of code.

Comment: you are amazing! Your code is simple and elegant. Thanks for sharing and thanks for helping. I know I shouldn't use table, but `div` caused lots of headache with me especially when I tried to "vertical center" elements within div. I don't want to use table, but really, table is the most convenience way for me right now :(